# ggplot rescaling legends via NA (then backfilling NA values)

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
heatmap <- tibble(col1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
                  col2 = rep(c("I", "II", "III"), 3),
                  col3 = c(1:8, 99))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   col1  col2   col3
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     I         1
#> 2 A     II        2
#> 3 A     III       3
#> 4 B     I         4
#> 5 B     II        5
#> 6 B     III       6
#> 7 C     I         7
#> 8 C     II        8
#> 9 C     III      99
```

I can create a heatmap from the data frame above that looks like this.

```
ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = col3))
```

[image: heat map 1]

The `C/III` value is `99` and makes the scale of the legend almost unusable. With that in mind I wrote the following code to rescale the legend for a "better" view on things.

```
ggplot(heatmap %>% mutate(col3 = ifelse(col3 > 10, NA, col3)), 
       aes(col1, col2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col3))
```

[image: heat map 2]

I want the end user to know the value of the original "NA" squares, but I don't want to clutter the rest of the heat map with labels for every other square. What I want is shown below.

[image: heat map 3]

How do I backfill my NA values to be able to use them with `geom_text()`, and how do I limit ggplot to only drawing labels on top of grey `NA` squares, not "normal" squares. The beginning of this may look something like the following.

```
ggplot(heatmap %>% mutate(col3 = ifelse(col3 > 10, NA, col3)), 
       aes(col1, col2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col3)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = col3))
```

Comment: I don't think you need `mutate` & `ifelse`. You may use `scale_fill_gradient(limits = `. Default is to replace values outside the limits with `NA`. Then use the `data` argument in `geom_text` to get labels only at the out-of-bounds values, `geom_text(data = heatmap[heatmap$col3 > 10 & !is.na(heatmap$col3), ])`

Comment: @Henrik that works great! So basically it would be `ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = col3)) + scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 10)) + geom_text(data = heatmap %>% mutate(col3 = ifelse(col3 > 10, col3, NA)), aes(label = col3))`

Comment: Again, you don't need `mutate` and `ifelse`. In `geom_text` just select the rows for which you want to add labels, as I showed above. Something like: `ggplot(heatmap, aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = col3, label = col3)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(data = heatmap[heatmap$col3 > 10 & !is.na(heatmap$col3), ]) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(min(heatmap$col3), 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took inspiration from @Henrik's comments and went with this:

```
ggplot(heatmap, aes(col1, col2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col3)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 10)) + 
  geom_text(data = heatmap %>% 
              mutate(col3 = ifelse(col3 > 10, col3, NA)), 
            aes(label = col3))
```

[image]